# SAS: how to create an index variable based on a string variable?

Tags: indexing, sas

I would like to create a sequential index variable. For example I have unique site and sections within sites:

Site 1 1 2 2 3 3

Section A B A B A B

Site-section combinations are unique. I would like a unique sequential index variable, so that Site 1, section A= 1 and Site 1, section B=2 and Site 2 section A=3, and so on.

Site 1 1 2 2 3 3

Section A B A B A B

Index 1 2 3 4 5 6

I've tried using first. and last. functions with do loops and I just can't figure it out. I'm not very good with do loops anyway.  Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is perfectly reasonable, particularly if you are not sure whether or not there are only unique values of site-section.  If you are sure that they are unique  (so, NODUPRECS does not remove anything), then you can simplify it and remove the merge:

```
data final;
set dataset;
sectionIndex+1;
run;
```

Optionally sorting before the datastep if you want them in proper order.

If you want to avoid the merge (if the dataset is very big) and you're NOT sure they are unique, then you can do:

```
proc sort data=dataset; 
by site section; 
run;

data final;
set dataset;
by site section;
if first.section then sectionIndex+1;
run;
```

This does not require NODUPRECS or NODUPKEY, and saves on some processing time.

I don't think a DO loop would be helpful, unless you were doing something more complicated (needing a DoW loop or something like that).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do this with a do loop, but apparently it can be accomplished using proc sort and data merge. Create dataset where only categorical variables used to create index are kept, then sort using noduprescs to remove duplicates. Add index variable with +1. Then merge back to original dataset.

```
data sitesections;
set dataset;
keep site section;

proc sort data=sitesections out=sitesections2 noduprecs;
by site section;

data sitesections_final;
set sitesections2;
sectionindex +1;

data final;
merge sitesections_final dataset;
by site section;
run;
```

Comment: If I can comment on style - a simple thing you can do to make your code more robust and more readable is add RUN statements to each of your steps.  While they are not actually necessary, it's generally a good habit to have RUN after each DATA and PROC step (except those that end in QUIT, like PROC SQL).  Makes it more readable (as it's more clear where one step ends and the next begins), and more maintainable (for example, if you need to test just one step).